# How to listen to GET and POST requests for all connections using GO

Tags: go, mitmproxy, get-request

I am using python and mitmproxy to listen to all incoming and outgoing traffic so that I can capture the URLs. I run the script and it tells me all URLs my computer is trying to connect to.

I need to implement the same using Go but have not got a clue on how to start or what package to use. Can anyone guide me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either easily build a proxy with [httputil](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httputil) - example [here](https://gist.github.com/JalfResi/6287706).
Or you might want to use [gopacket](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/gopacket) as described [here](https://blog.apnic.net/2021/05/12/programmatically-analyse-packet-captures-with-gopacket/).

Answer (score 0):

You would need a local intermediate proxy, in order to capture its traffic and display the URLs used.

See for example, in Go, [`sipt/shuttle`](https://github.com/sipt/shuttle), with its GUI web interface:

[image: https://github.com/sipt/shuttle/blob/master/static/cert.jpg?raw=true]